# How to change values between columns which have same colnames

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, subset

I would like to replace certain columns of a data frame with columns from another data frame if the column names match:

I extracted some numeric columns from a data.frame named `train`. Then I made a second data.frame named `all_box` which contain column-wise boxcox transformations of `train`. After that, I want to replace those imputed data(all_box) with part of original data(train) finding by same colnames. My code was this..

I was trying to change value if the colnames are same or did not want to change any of it.

```
for(i in 1:length(train)){

  train[,i]<-ifelse(colnames(train)[i]%in%colnames(all_box),

                    dplyr::select(all_box,colnames(train[i])),
                    dplyr::select(train,colnames(train[i])))
  }
```

but I get the error:

> Error: Unknown column `id`  Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a
>   backtrace

(column 'id' is the name of first column of original data which I do not want to make any change)

Comment: Can you share your data so others can troubleshoot. I think the error is from the `select` statements. Meaning those `select` statements produce `tibbles` and not vectors - which is what the `ifelse` is looking for. Need data to verify though.

Answer (score 0):

the `ifelse` function should not be used in this case. Try this:

```
train2 <- train
my_cols <- colnames(train)[colnames(train) %in% colnames(all_box)]
train2[, my_cols] <- all_box[, my_cols]
```